# Mqtt connection & data publisher misinterpreted in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I have jmeter , where a single thread contains two mqtt gateway connection sampler & each sampler have three publishers connected to iothub.

Jmeter reference:

[image: Thread & gateway connection]

When I run the thread in loop 6frames / second for 10 seconds, I could see all 60 frames published successful in JMeter.

But when I check data count at iothub, first gate way point  have received only 6 frames ( some data get missed it seems, problem with jmeter I assume )  & second gateway have received  42 frames. Second part led to major confusion, when it have to receive maximum of 30 frames, but received 42.

Diagram reference:

[image: Jmeter vs iothub]

Each gateway (A &B)  include the Connection panel with :

```
Iothub URL 
Mqtt v 3.1.1
Username: iothuburl/device ID
Pwd: SAS token ( generated SAS from connection string available at iothubowner page from azure portal).
```

Each  Gateway (A&B) include

```
        three publishers &  Each includes 200 JSON objects and size doesn't exceed 55kb. 

        Publisher QoS: 0
```

Operation:

```
       For every one second, each gateway publish 3 frames ( total 600 JSON objects).

        As I have mentioned 2 gateway, so total 6 frames with 1200 JSON object get published successful in JMeter.
```

But the data is missing at iothub.

note: while running two gateway  in single thread, i could both gateway connection sharing the common connection string ID.

Any clue, where did I miss the major configuration, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The question currently doesn't make it clear what your architecture is. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61331708/edit) the question to explain all the parts, may be add a diagram to explain the relationship between the JMeter instances, gateways and hub. Also do you have some load balancing involved here?

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, I was looking for a diagram with the logical layout of all t he components. Also what QOS are you publishing your messages at

Comment: Yes I have included afew more details. Pls let me know if the content make any sense to provide any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the QoS=1 in publisher panel. Though we have few latency time to wait for acknowledgement, but the simulation works fine without any loss of  connection/data.